# Ubuntu 16.04 Download

Tags: 16.04, security

I want to download Ubuntu 16.04 from ubuntu.com and I noticed that the web site is not https secured.

It means that the web site starts with http://

Does it mean that the downloaded image can be manipulated?

I understand that I can verify it using md5 or similar. But is there any chance of downloading corrupted iso like malware?

Comment: HTTP vs. HTTPS doesn't mean anything when it comes to file integrity/security.  Take a look at how many 'bad guy' sites have free Lets Encrypt certificates and you'll see what I mean.  Your concern should ONLY be the SHA512s matching the *official* ones on http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Comment: Another option is to use the BitTorrent protocol, which automatically verifies the integrity of the download.  Downloading via torrent often has the added bonus of faster download speeds. See: https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 1):

The download page can be in fact used with https, it seems you're just using an http version of it. See: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Also, the iso won't be executed as soon as you download it. It contains a kind of file system which you need to open first (or put on a USB stick) to run.

While it is true that the data could be manipulated during transfer if you only use http, it is not only unlikely to happen, but you'd verify it with the hash after downloading it. Especially when it came from an http source. Your bigger concern should probably be that the file was tampered with beforehand when downloading it from a non-trustworthy website, even if it does have https.

Comment: The 16.04 is available under releases.ubuntu.com once I try to add a https:// the connection does not work.